# Knees hurt after running a few days in a row. Injury possible?

Tags: running, injury

I don't have any pain if I walk for an hour or so. I walk to work every day (2 x 20 mins). I take long walks on weekends, but no knee pain after that. I started running. Small distances at first (2.5 - 3 km), then longer ones (5 - 6km). After third day of running long distance I felt pain in outer area of my knees. I wanted to know if this is temporary and if I should see a doctor because of this? Should I stop running or just shorten the distances I run and start lengthening them once my legs are more used to it?

Comment: Conventional wisdom suggests avoiding increases in mileage (kilometer-age??) more than 10% per week, so it sounds like you might be overdoing it. If you aren't **injured**, then just pull it back. Go back to walking and short jogs and gradually build up.

Comment: If it is both knees I highly doubt it is an injury and more a case of new found exertion on your knees. Take a week off and then focus on amount of time running, not distance and increase that time in a gradual fashion. There are [programs](http://www.runnersworld.com/article/0,7120,s6-238-520--9397-0,00.html) that can aid you in this endeavor.

Comment: `Injury possible?` was a question whether injury is possible if I continue running. I'm not injured. I have about 15kg of overweight. So just wondered if it's from the extra weight that my knees aren't used to carrying on certain speeds and amount of time. Anyway - thank you very much for the tips!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is definitely not a good idea for you to continue without consulting a doctor or a physiotherapist.  Based on my personal experience, I think you should starr by consulting a physiotherapist. They will look at your joints, spine, muscles, etc. They will give you corrective measures and exercises to do. My physiotherapist also took the time to analyze my running and told me how to adjust because I was not running properly. Overall, I do not struggle with sore knees anymore thanks to my physiotherapist!

Comment: Agree with recommendation to see a physio. On that very short description it sounds like ITB syndrome which is very easily treated and managed if you get on to it early. Waiting causes many more problems.